# Tokenizing string with Javascript including not matching blocks

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
Test block {{section1|val}}
test block
{| class="class1"
some test
|}
```

I would like to get the following elements:

- `Test block`
- `{{section1|val}}`
- `test block`
- `{| class="class1"\nsome test\n|}`

I can get blocks with `{` / `}` around with the following regexp:

```
const regex = /(\{(.|[\r\n])*?)\}/g;
const matches = content.match(regex);
```

But how can I get in the same time other text blocks.

Thanks for your help!
Thierry

Comment: check this https://regex101.com/r/Q3I0zG/1 is this you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple two alternation regex should do your job.

```
\w+(?:\s+\w+)*|\{+[\w\W]*?\}+
```

Here, `\w+(?:\s+\w+)*` regex matches strings of normal text `abc` or `abc xyx` and `\{+[\w\W]*?\}+` regex matches text of type `{{abc}}` or `{xyz}`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ab2IcI/1)**

```js
var s = `Test block {{section1|val}}
test block
{| class="class1"
some test
|}`;

var arr = s.match(/\w+(?:\s+\w+)|\{+[\w\W]*?\}+/g);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate between the `{{ }}` separators, the `{| }}` separators, and anything but a `{`:

```js
const input = `Test block {{section1|val}}
test block
{| class="class1"
some test
|}`;
console.log(input.match(/{{.*?}}|{\|.*?\|}|[^{]+/gs));
```

If you don't want to match leading/trailing spaces outside of separators, then change to

```
{{.*?}}|{\|.*?\|}|\S[^{]+[^{\s]
                  ^^     ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answer! But it seems that this regex doesn't catch additional text at the end of the string...

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

`[^{]+` - Matching plain text before `{`.

`{[^}]+}}?` - Matching text between `{}`.

```js
let str = `Test block {{section1|val}}
test block
{| class="class1"
some test
|} foo bar`

let temp = str.match(/[^{]+|{[^}]+}}?/g)

let op = temp.map(e=> e.trim().replace(/^\n|\n$/g,''))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answer! But it seems that this regex doesn't catch additional text at the end of the string...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier didn't understand what you mean additional content at end of string ? any case example ? will definitely improve if i missed one

Comment: @ThierryTemplier i added a string at end. and it seems to work. any way accepted answer is better than mine.